# Kafka consumer returns empty on second call

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I insert a record to Kafka producer and then call consumer which returns the inserted element (and previously inserted elements) then I call the customer again (without inserting new record with producer) the consumer does not return any records.

As far as I know the record should remain in topic. I have no idea how to set acknowledge to false in properties. Is this issue related to acknowledgment?

Answer (score 0):

The consumer will only get "new" messages. If you have previously read until the end of the topic and there is nothing new, you won't get anything.

If you want to read from the beginning of the topic again, you have to "rewind" the consumer (or create a new one).

> I have no idea how to set acknowledge to false in properties(is this issue related to acknowledgment?)

If you use consumer groups, the offsets for the consumer (how far it is read each topic partition) will be stored within Kafka (or Zookeeper for older versions). You can control this by acknowledging (or not) the receipt of messages. However, this only has an effect when the consumer is restarted, not for an already running instance.

If you don't use consumer groups, this offset tracking is purely done within the consumer instance itself.